# check harddisk specs for iMac

Tags: mac, hard-drive, osx-lion

There are programs on windows to really get into the detail specs of one's harddrive, such as how many hours has it been used for and stuff. Is there such app for Mac OS, Lion? Thanks

Comment: More than likely the spec's you've seen are not OS specific but generic firmware style information which can be accessed through the manufacturors utilities usually loaded from a bootable CDROM or 'native' enviroment. [Hiren's BOOT CD](http://www.hiren.info) has alot of these.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lion's disk utility can display a lot of this information, although it shows the raw hexadecimal values without interpretation.  To get it, run Disk Utility, select the drive from the sidebar (not the volume under it), and click the Info button in the toolbar.

[image: Example info window]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it can provide information like hours used, but the **System Information** under *utilities* is helpful:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[Smart Utility](http://www.volitans-software.com/smart_utility.php) (shareware) can do that.

[Disk Radar](http://diskradar.com/) (shareware) is also capable of displaying [SMART](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M.A.R.T.) information, although it's primarily a "Show me how my disk space is used" utility.

[SMART Reporter](http://www.corecode.at/smartreporter/) is free, but doesn't really show a lot of information. It focuses on alerting you when some of the values (pre-fail) indicate an impending problem.